# How can I make a policy that trigger when a workflow's task change some property?

Tags: java, lucene, workflow, alfresco

I am trying to execute code when someone change the value of the properties of a task.

This is my code:

```
public void init() {
  JavaBehaviour updateBehaviour = new JavaBehaviour(this,
      OnUpdatePropertiesPolicy.QNAME.getLocalName(),
    NotificationFrequency.TRANSACTION_COMMIT);

  policyComponent.bindClassBehaviour(OnUpdatePropertiesPolicy.QNAME,
    WorkflowModel.TYPE_TASK, updateBehaviour);

  policyComponent.bindClassBehaviour(OnUpdatePropertiesPolicy.QNAME,
    WorkflowModel.TYPE_START_TASK, updateBehaviour);

  policyComponent.bindClassBehaviour(OnUpdatePropertiesPolicy.QNAME,
    WorkflowModel.TYPE_ACTIVTI_TASK, updateBehaviour);

  policyComponent.bindClassBehaviour(OnUpdatePropertiesPolicy.QNAME,
    WorkflowModel.TYPE_ACTIVTI_START_TASK, updateBehaviour);

  policyComponent.bindClassBehaviour(OnUpdatePropertiesPolicy.QNAME,
    WorkflowModel.TYPE_WORKFLOW_TASK, updateBehaviour);

  logger.debug("Initialised"); // the program prints this line
}

public void onUpdateProperties(NodeRef nodeRef, Map<QName, Serializable> 
    before, Map<QName, Serializable> after) {
  String msg = String.format("NodeRef: %s", nodeRef.toString());
  logger.info(msg);    // this line is never printed 
}
```

I created a policy for almost all the types related with the tasks. But if I change the value by hand of some properties in a task the policy is never triggered.

Maybe it is related. I tried to query in Lucene somes queries like:

```
@bpm\:priority:1
TYPE:"bpm:task"
```

Without any result. And I have many tasks created.

I am using Alfresco 4.1 (it is out of my hands to change the version)

Comment: Interesting, I don't think I've ever seen anyone try to use a behavior with a workflow task and I'm not sure it will even work. Why can't you just add a task listener to your workflow?

Comment: I tried the task listeners, but there is no way to make it trigger a task property change. But I found an alternative way

Answer (score 0):

I found that is not possible to bind a policy to a workflow, but I found an alternative methodology.

With the AbstractFilter we can attach a behaviour each time someone change the properties of a task using the form.

```
public class TaskFormFilter extends AbstractFilter<WorkflowTask, WorkflowTask>  {
  public void init() {
    if (this.isActive()) {
      this.register();
    }
  }
  ...
  @Override
  public void afterPersist(WorkflowTask item, FormData data,  
     WorkflowTask persistedObject) {
     Map<QName, Serializable> newProperties = item.getProperties();
     Map<QName, Serializable> oldProperties = persistedObject.getProperties();
     // here I can see if some properties has changed
     ...
  }
}
```

There is not a task listener that get triggered when a task property has changed